# Converting array of characters to an array of key-codes c++

Tags: c++, arrays, keyboard, key

I'm trying to make an array of chars , taken from the user , to key-codes

For example if the user inputs:
"a"

the key-code will be: 0x41.

Anyway to do it? or is it hardware specific?
because in MSDN theres a list of all key-codes that match exactly to my keyboard.

If that's not possible please state.

if there is another way to capture these from the user , please inform.

Comment: if you just want the ASCII code as an integer value, just convert your char to int.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert to an int your char with the following code :

```cpp
char inputChar = 'a'
int outputAscii = (int)inputChar;
```

The output value will be 41 for 'a'. If you really need the 0x before, you can concat in a string again.

Comment: thats not what i asked for... and the value for 'a' is 97 in decimal + that casting is not needed.